# Avoiding ODR violations when using debug asserts

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

I have a header-only library that has some additional fail-fast runtime assertions enabled when compiled in debug mode. A simplified version of the header looks like this:

```
#include <exception>

#ifdef MYDEBUG
#   define MYASSERT(condition) do{ if (!(condition)) std::terminate(); } while(0)
#else
#   define MYASSERT(condition)
#endif

template<typename T>
class Checker
{
public:

    T operator()(T value)
    {
        MYASSERT(value);
        return value;
    }
};
```

If one translation unit includes the header without defining `MYDEBUG` first, and another one includes it after defining `MYDEBUG`, and I link the resultant object files together, would that constitute an ODR violation?

How can I avoid this but still allow each TU to independently specify its desired assertion settings when including the header?

Comment: Why not use `MYDEBUG` as a compile-time parameter of your conversion operator? `T operator()(T value) { return do_conversion(value, MYDEBUG); }`, where `do_conversion` may or may not contain the assert

Answer (score 3):

> If one translation unit includes the header without defining `MYDEBUG` first, and another one includes it after defining `MYDEBUG`, and I link the resultant object files together, would that constitute an ODR violation?

Yes, it is a violations of the one-definition-rule. It's a violation of the rule for inline functions that says the inline function definitions must have the exact tokens in all the translation units.

> How can I avoid this but still allow each TU to independently specify its desired assertion settings when including the header?

<strike>One way to deal with is to define `MYASSERT` to be file scoped `static` functions.</strike>

```
#ifdef MYDEBUG
static void MYASSERT(bool condition)
{
   if (!(condition))
   {
      std::terminate();
   }
}
#else
static void MYASSERT(bool condition)
{
   // Noop
}
#endif
```

It appears that you cannot. Thanks, @RustyX.

Comment: Nope, still a violation of [\[basic.def.odr\]/12.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#12.2). The idea of a single definition is to avoid issues should the linker have to fold multiple definitions, for example if the function was virtual or called via a pointer. There will actually be just one version left.

Comment: `There can be more than one definition of a [...] inline function with external linkage, [...] non-static function template, [...] provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements.`

Comment: @sp2danny - sure. it's `operator()` that still violates ODR.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** use scoping:

```
#ifdef MYDEBUG
#   define MYASSERT(condition) do{ if (!(condition)) std::terminate(); } while(0)
#else
#   define MYASSERT(condition)
#endif

namespace {
  template<typename T>
  class Checker
  {
  public:
      T operator()(T value)
      {
          MYASSERT(value);
          return value;
      }
  };
}
```

This essentially changes `Checker` to internal linkage, and potentially comes with extra cost, that is it can end up in the final executable multiple times. However, in this particular case there's no extra cost as it will probably be inlined anyway.

**Solution 2:** parameterize the template on the debug mode:

(*Update 3: using template specialization thanks to @Jarod42's suggestion*)

```
#ifdef MYDEBUG
#   define MYASSERT(condition) do{ if (!(condition)) std::terminate(); } while(0)
#   define MYDEBUG_FLAG true
#else
#   define MYASSERT(condition)
#   define MYDEBUG_FLAG false
#endif

template<typename T, bool = MYDEBUG_FLAG> class Checker;

template<typename T>
class Checker<T, MYDEBUG_FLAG>
{
public:
    T operator()(T value)
    {
        MYASSERT(value);
        return value;
    }
};
```

Then the debug- and non-debug instantiations will be independent of each other.

The nice thing about this is even if one accidentally instantiates `Checker<T, !MYDEBUG_FLAG>`, it won't compile and hence won't violate ODR (provided only one version, either debug- or non-debug, is ever defined in each TU).

Comment: I believe this code still technically violates ODR, since default values for template arguments are not part of the definition.

Comment: partial specialization should solve that issue, no ?

Comment: @Jarod42, it should, but I am not sure how you are planning on selecting it?

Comment: @SergeyA: Like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2540422069a17313) ? (Declarations Differ, but definitions are identical).

Comment: @Jarod42 that's clever I and see no reason why it won't work. Care to add this as an answer? Even if OP doesn't like it, I'd certainly upvote.

Comment: @SergeyA - thanks. answer improved. Should work now I think?

Comment: @RustyX I do not think so. It seems to be violating ODR for the template itself?

Comment: Third time's the charm (I hope). It's a variant of Jarod's suggestion, but without redefining the whole class (I think OP definitely doesn't want to define the whole class twice)

Answer (score 0):

Variant of first RustyX's answer, but fixed I think:

```
#ifdef MYDEBUG
#   define MYDEBUG_FLAG true
#else
#   define MYDEBUG_FLAG false
#endif

#define MYASSERT(condition) do{ if (!(condition)) std::terminate(); } while(0)

// Following declaration differs, but doesn't break ODR.
template<typename T, bool = MYDEBUG_FLAG> class Checker;

// And both definitions of specialization.
template <typename T>
class Checker<T, true>
{
public:

    T operator()(T value)
    {
        MYASSERT(value);
        return value;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Checker<T, false>
{
public:

    T operator()(T value)
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Comment: @RustyX: What is true is that users have to handle the mix of `Checker<T, true>`/`Checker<T, false>` when mixing `MYDEBUG` flag (which I think is a blocking (unsolvable) issue)...